# Speeding up slow SELECT query (Postgresql 9.6)

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

In a app called **Links**, users post photos of interesting content they've discovered recently (and others can vote or comment on them).

These posted photos are saved in a `links_photo` table in my postgresql 9.6.5 DB.

Each user's profile shows their posted photos - paginated by `10` objects each - ordered by `upload time`.

One `SELECT` query on the `links_photo` table is consistently showing up in `slow_log`. It's taking longer than 500ms, and is ~10X slower than what I'm experiencing in most other postgresql operations.

Here's an example of the corresponding SQL from my slow log:

**LOG:  duration: 542.755 ms  statement:**

```
SELECT "links_photo"."id",
       "links_photo"."owner_id",
       "links_photo"."image_file",
       "links_photo"."upload_time",
       "links_photo"."comment_count",
       "links_photo"."vote_score",
       "links_photo"."caption",
       "links_photo"."category",
       "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."username",
       "auth_user"."date_joined",
       "links_userprofile"."id",
       "links_userprofile"."user_id",
       "links_userprofile"."score",
       "links_userprofile"."avatar"
FROM   "links_photo"
       INNER JOIN "auth_user"
               ON ( "links_photo"."owner_id" = "auth_user"."id" )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "links_userprofile"
                    ON ( "auth_user"."id" = "links_userprofile"."user_id" )
WHERE  ( "links_photo"."owner_id" = 78689
         AND "links_photo"."category" = '1' )
ORDER  BY "links_photo"."upload_time" DESC
LIMIT  10 offset 10
```

See the the `explain analyze` results: https://explain.depesz.com/s/DPJo

According to that, the Index Scan Backward ends up filtering 1,196,188 rows and is the source of slowness.

**What I think I should try:**

Being an accidental DBA of sorts, I'm looking for some quick expert guidance on the subject. I would have thought having an index on `upload_time` would suffice, but it doesn't. So perhaps a composite one on `(owner_id, upload_time DESC)`?

**Addition:**

Here's the entire output for `\d links_photo`:

```
                                           Table "public.links_photo"
          Column          |           Type           |                        Modifiers                         
--------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id                       | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_photo_id_seq'::regclass)
 owner_id                 | integer                  | not null
 image_file               | character varying(100)   | not null
 upload_time              | timestamp with time zone | not null
 comment_count            | integer                  | not null
 is_public                | boolean                  | not null
 vote_score               | integer                  | not null
 visible_score            | integer                  | not null
 invisible_score          | double precision         | not null
 caption                  | character varying(100)   | 
 avg_hash                 | character varying(16)    | not null
 latest_comment_id        | integer                  | 
 second_latest_comment_id | integer                  | 
 category                 | character varying(11)    | not null
 device                   | character varying(10)    | not null
Indexes:
    "links_photo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_photo_latest_comment_id" btree (latest_comment_id)
    "links_photo_owner_id" btree (owner_id)
    "links_photo_second_latest_comment_id" btree (second_latest_comment_id)
    "links_photo_upload_time" btree (upload_time)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "latest_comment_id_refs_id_f2566197" FOREIGN KEY (latest_comment_id) REFERENCES links_photocomment(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_photo_owner_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "second_latest_comment_id_refs_id_f2566197" FOREIGN KEY (second_latest_comment_id) REFERENCES links_photocomment(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_photostream" CONSTRAINT "cover_id_refs_id_d62b783f" FOREIGN KEY (cover_id) REFERENCES links_photo(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_photocomment" CONSTRAINT "links_photocomment_which_photo_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_photo_id) REFERENCES links_photo(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_photoobjectsubscription" CONSTRAINT "links_photoobjectsubscription_which_photo_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_photo_id) REFERENCES links_photo(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_photovote" CONSTRAINT "links_photovote_photo_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (photo_id) REFERENCES links_photo(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_report" CONSTRAINT "links_report_which_photo_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_photo_id) REFERENCES links_photo(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_photo_which_stream" CONSTRAINT "photo_id_refs_id_916b4355" FOREIGN KEY (photo_id) REFERENCES links_photo(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same case like you. The problem is `Rows Removed by Filter`, the query takes time to remove rows by its filter. Depending on how many rows will be removed, the time will be equivalent.

**Idea 1**

Your approach is fine. The small thing is the query needs to remove rows on the `category`. However, it is not a big problem if your [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)) on `category` is not much.

**Idea 2**

I would suggest to create index on `owner_id, category, upload_time DESC`. It will avoid `the filter`. But, you should consider the size of index in case of large table.

Let  say we have the table ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d700ba2ade9390e4ea88b7545f03390d))

```
CREATE TABLE links_photo 
(
  id serial, 
  owner_id int, 
  category int, 
  upload_time timestamp without time zone
);
```

And the query

```
SELECT id
FROM links_photo 
WHERE owner_id = 100 and category = 2 
ORDER BY upload_time desc 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0;
```

[The explanation of](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Ddrd) using `upload_time DESC`

[The explanation of](https://explain.depesz.com/s/NFqi) using `owner_id, upload_time DESC`

[The explanation of](https://explain.depesz.com/s/e6WF) using `owner_id, category, upload_time DESC`

Comment: Great depth in your answer. Your idea worked better than mine, so I'm going with that (created index isn't huge). I now want to delete the index I created in idea 1. What's the best way to do that without any downtime? Outside the scope of this question, thus I'm marking your answer anyhow.

Comment: Please consider using [CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createindex.html) . It requires [SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/explicit-locking.html) in your table, i.e. you can read/write data in the table during that time.

Comment: Yep, I used "create index concurrently" for this so that concurrent ops aren't affected. But I was referring to dropping the index I created when implementing **idea 1**

Comment: As in, should I try `DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY <index_name>`?

Comment: Ah, correct `drop index concurrently <index name>`.